# Is there general component which for data loading in aikau?

Tags: javascript, dojo, aikau

The simple searching `loadDataPublishTopic` on aikau sources gives the following results:

- AlfDocument.js
- PropertyPicker.js
- SimplePicker.js
- AlfList.js
- Paginator.js
- UserList.js
- lib.js
- lib.js
- SitePicker.js
- CommentsList.js
- DataListService.js
- lib.js
- get.js

Most of example use `AlfList`, if you at the list upper, you will find that all components are to specific. Am I right that there is not general component (or component container) with data loading? E.g. something like `SelfLoadableWidget` or `SelfLoadablePanel` which loads data which can be used by their child widgets?

**Note**

Aikua version is `1.0.97.1`.

Answer (score 0):

It still doesn't sound like you've worked through the [tutorial](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/blob/develop/tutorial/chapters/About.md) (as I've suggested in answers to your previous questions) as a lot of this information is covered.

Essentially the whole idea is that data and display are decoupled. The [AlfList](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/AlfList.html) (and its descendants) can be used to render lists of any data. The list widgets are solely responsible for managing the state of the data and delegate the presentation of the data to one or more view (see [AlfListView](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/AlfListView.html)).

Data to be rendered in the list can either be provided directly in the configuration of the list (via `currentData`) or requested via a service. A generic service exists ([CrudService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/CrudService.html)) that you can publish to providing the URL for the REST API you wish to call, but its preferable to use one of the many services dedicated to the specific data you want to work with (such as [DocumentService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/DocumentService.html), [UserService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/UserService.html), etc).

There is no "self-loading" components - however you can quite easily extend AlfList (or any of its descendants) and override the `loadData` function.